# Capture stdout of a function called from another file in C

Tags: c, linux

I've trying to figure out how to capture the stdout of a function from another file and capture its stdout to a buffer in the current file.

i.e. File: B

```
printfInfo() 
{
    ....
    printf("Information: description\n"); 
    printf("Date: date\n");
    ....
    return OK;
}
```

and in File: A

```
funcA() 
{
    ....
    result = printInfo(); //capture stdout of the function here

}
```

So far I tried dup and `dup2` but cant get it to redirect the stdout to a buffer. Is there another way to capture `printInfo()`'s `stdout` without using a pipe or filesystem?

Comment: Another file? Process? Or function? You should decide on it..

Comment: Using [fifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo)?

Comment: @MikeCAT Doesn't it count as a pipe? BTW, what's wrong with pipes, again?

Comment: Another file. my bad for not being clear enough. i keep getting "pipe" undeclared as a compilation error tho I have unistd declared as include.

Comment: So you want to ask a question on this compilation error.

Comment: @alk Probably not since I cant make any changes to any of the files i.e. makefile apart from the file im working on.

Comment: A different file or function is not the same as a different process - you have clarified that in your comment, but you should edit your question and title to reflect the actual situation.  You should also ask a question about your actual *problem* rather than your intended *solution* - someone may have a better solution.

Comment: Functions don't have a stdout of their own, its global to the process the functions run in. All functions running in the same process (i.e. the same program) will use the same stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You might redirect stdout to a file using [`freopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/), before calling `funcB()`and then read the output from that file after it returns.  If you need to restore the stdout after, then that can be done using `dup()` and `dup2()` as follows:

```
void funcA() 
{
    int stdout_restore = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    FILE* redirected = freopen ("stdoutcapture.txt","w",stdout);
    res = funcB(); 
    fclose( redirected ) ; 
    dup2( stdout_restore, STDOUT_FILENO ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i will try this

Comment: tried this but the place where i am running the code doesnt have a write access. Is there a way to straightly capture this to a buffer? instead of a file?

Comment: @John : could you not create the file in a writeable path? It need not be in the cwd. The most obvious method is to use the path returned by [mktemp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktemp.3.html).

Comment: @mktemp() Found out that the board im working on doesnt have filesystem, will try to sort out this first

Comment: @John : Is it even possible to run Linux without a file system? Create a RAM disk perhaps?

Comment: If there's [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) support, then you could use that?